# strange behavior of sklearn random forest classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to use sklearn random forest classifier (in python), and I get some strange results

my function is:

```
    rf = tree(data_handler.train_dataset, data_handler.train_labels, num_of_estimemtors, tree_depth, 42, tree_max_featrues)        
    # evaluate(rf, data_handler.train_dataset, data_handler.train_labels)
    evaluate(rf, data_handler.test_dataset, data_handler.test_labels)
```

(to the implementation of "tree" and "evaluate" see below)

when there is a comment on the second line, the results are awful:

```
 0.4772727272727273
[[ 0 23]
 [ 0 21]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00        23
           1       0.48      1.00      0.65        21

    accuracy                           0.48        44
   macro avg       0.24      0.50      0.32        44
weighted avg       0.23      0.48      0.31        44
```

but, when this line is uncommented, the results change dramatically:

```
0.9846153846153847
[[1235    0]
 [  38 1197]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.97      1.00      0.98      1235
           1       1.00      0.97      0.98      1235

    accuracy                           0.98      2470
   macro avg       0.99      0.98      0.98      2470
weighted avg       0.99      0.98      0.98      2470

0.5909090909090909
[[ 8 15]
 [ 3 18]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.73      0.35      0.47        23
           1       0.55      0.86      0.67        21

    accuracy                           0.59        44
   macro avg       0.64      0.60      0.57        44
weighted avg       0.64      0.59      0.56        44
```

this function does not suppose to change rf (the random forest). I tried to make sense of that for half a day and I have failed. what's wrong here?

function implementations:

```
def evaluate(rf, x, y):
    pred = rf.predict(x)
    print(accuracy_score(y, pred))
    print(confusion_matrix(y, pred))
    print(classification_report(y, pred))
    return accuracy_score(y, pred)
    
def tree(x, y, est, depth, seed=42, max_features="auto"):
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = est, max_depth=depth, random_state=seed, bootstrap=True, max_features=max_features)
    rf.fit(x,y)
    return rf
```

Comment: Bootrstraping introduces some form of randomness, is this result consistent across multiple runs?

Comment: yes, it was consistent

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are seeing a huge drop in the model's performance metrics when you evaluate the model with `test_dataset` and `test_labels`.

> this function does not suppose to change rf (the random forest). I tried to make sense of that for half a day and I have failed. what's wrong here?

You did not show the values passed to `tree`, but it's possible that your model is overfitting. I suggest you retrain `rf` with a lower `max_depth`, a greater number of `n_estimators` or a smaller number of `max_features`. In fact, you can run a [Grid Search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to find the best combination of hyperparameters.

Once again, I have no idea what your current hyperparameters are, but based on personal experience, I have found that a `max_depth` of around 5 results in models that typically generalize well.

Comment: actually, my max_depth is 2. I know that the model is overfitting but that is not my problem. my problem is the unexplainable change in performance